# primefaces dialog not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to replicate primefaces ajax dialog form as in Primefaces showcase

My JSF code snippet is as below

```
<h:body>  

<p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" type="button" value="Show"  
    onclick="PF('dlg').show()" />  

<p:dialog header="Enter FirstName" widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true"  
    resizable="false">  
    <h:form id="form">  

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">  
            <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="firstName:" />  
            <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{backingBean.firstName}" />  
        </h:panelGrid>  

        <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" update=":display"  
            oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide();" />  

    </h:form>  
</p:dialog>  

<p:outputPanel id="display" style="display:block;margin-top:10px;">  
    <h:outputText id="name" value="Hello #{backingBean.firstName}"  
        rendered="#{not empty backingBean.firstName}" />  
</p:outputPanel>
```

My managed bean

```
@ManagedBean  
@ViewScoped  

public class BackingBean implements Serializable{  


    private String firstName;  

    public String getFirstName() {  
        return firstName;  
    }  

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {  
        this.firstName = firstName;  
    }  


}
```

No dialog is getting displayed on clicking submit button :(. I have also included appendToBody="true" but no result.In ie i get javascript error as "Object Expected". Please help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

which version of primefaces you use ?

If you use Primefaces 3.5 or older:

```
<p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" type="button" value="Show"  
    onclick="dlg.show()" />
```

For Primefaces 4.0 :

```
<p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" type="button" value="Show"  
    onclick="PF('dlg').show()" />
```

Comment: Is the second one a javascript call? I just want to know the difference between those two calls.

Comment: Thanks a ton Lamq.I am using PF 3.5,as u mentioned ,this can only work with onclick="dlg.show()

Comment: what is the name for the `JavaScript` derivative dialect that assigned here as a value to the `onclick` attribute?  I am just looking for the name of the dialect or expression language within `PrimeFaces`

Comment: I use Primefaces 3.5 , but  onclick="dlg.show()" doesnt works in IE10-11.
So what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a script link to jquery in header. I droped it and primefaces started to work correctly